# Get all contents within tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get all the contents within the article tag on lets say http://magazine.magix.com/de/5-tipps-fuer-die-fotobearbeitung/

However, when using

```
print soup.article
```

It will only go as far as "...Foto auf verschiedene Art und Weise und für verschiedene Zwecke bearbeiten. "

Whole Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

request_page = requests.get('http://magazine.magix.com/de/5-tipps-fuer-die-fotobearbeitung/', 'html.parser')
source = request_page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
print soup.article.text
```

How can I get everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, finally found. Welcome to the amazing world of scraping.

Within the `<article>` tag, some `</br>` tags exists, the guy surelly means `<br/>`.

Anyway, it breaks html flow, so BS struggles to parse it.

Here is how I solved it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

request_page = requests.get('http://magazine.magix.com/de/5-tipps-fuer-die-fotobearbeitung/', 'html.parser')
source = request_page.text
source = source.replace('</br>', '<br/>')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
print soup.article
```

(I replaced `</br>` to `<br/>`...)

This is a great scraping leason, this kind of stuff are legion, count on that :)

Comment: Nice catch! +1 for that

Comment: I guess there is no page that is without errors, sounds like alot of fiddling. Love it :D thanks dude!